# Firebase request.auth.id seems to contain no data

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am trying to create document in collection device if user is authenticated and I have defined below security rule:

```
 match /{devices}/{id=**}{
     allow write : if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
```

With following code :

```
 this.auth.onAuthStateChanged().subscribe(user => {
        if (user) {
          const docRef = this.afs.collection('devices');
          const docData = {
          uid: user.uid
          }
         alert(firebase.auth().currentUser);
         return docRef.doc(user.uid).set(docData);
        }
```

This is not creating a document and firebase.auth().currentUser outputs

> null

Just to check if there's any issue with request.auth.uid I tried changing rule to:

```
 allow write : if request.auth.uid == null;
```

But document is not getting created in this case too.

I am using phone as my Sign-In method and verifying phone number using https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-x , I could see my number getting authenticated and an user for my number in firebase console.
Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Are you doing any error checking on the call to `set()`? What is the error in each case? Please edit the question to include more details.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am getting an error ```permission-denied , Missing or insufficient permissions.```

Comment: That sounds like the user is not signed in. You can check this by printing `console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser)` right before `docRef.doc(token).set(docData)`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen firebase.auth().currentUser gives ```null```. I don't know why it says null since I can see user in firebase console and I can get the current user ID by ```onAuthStateChanged()``` method provided by https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-authentication

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am using the https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-x to sign-in because to avoid reCAPTCHA of ```firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber```. Is it possible to skip reCAPTCHA in ```firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber```

Comment: This typically means that you're trying to write before (possibly *just* before) the user is actually signed in. You might want to try writing *inside* the `onAuthStateChanged` handler.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen code to create document is actually inside ```onAuthStateChanged``` handler.

Comment: Instead of describing where the code is, please edit your question to show exactly that (including where you log the current user, and its output).